# Practical application of a sparse matrix?

Tags: java, sparse-matrix

In my class, we were learning about a sparse matrix such as how it works, etc. But it never mentioned why a sparse matrix is used or a practical application of one. I was wondering if someone could help me understand its purpose/application. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you have googled this already, what would you like to know?

Comment: Speak up in class .. that is what the professor is waiting for!

Comment: I think more of an example of one. I understand that it can be used for computing large scale applications, etc. For example, in a working environment for programmers, how would this fit into something they are working on?